# How to prevent hashicorp vault from sealing?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Our hashicorp vault deployment on k8s (on premise) seem to seal itself after few days. I am unable to find a way to keep it always unsealed so that applications which are using it do not fail.

Comment: You should use some of supported provider 
 for auto-unseal according to documentation https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/seal#auto-unseal

Comment: How many pods you are running to form vault cluster?

Comment: That is not a solution. Auto unsealing happens using a new Vault instance (or other method) but still requires a new entity than itself can be sealed, so the issue the users can face will be the 'unsealing of the unseal Vault'. Preventing the Vault from sealing would not require any new entities and would result in the Vault never sealing (insted of sealing and auto-unsealing which process might break, leaving the Vault in a sealed state).

Answer (score 0):

Activate auto-unsealing. Here's my GCP example, in Terraform (I am running Hashicorp Vault on Kubernetes).

```
resource "google_service_account" "hashicorp_vault" {
  project      = var.project
  account_id   = "hashicorp-vault"
  display_name = "Hashicorp Vault Service Account"
}

resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "hashicorp_vault_iam_workload_identity_user_member" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.hashicorp_vault.name
  role               = "roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser"
  member             = "serviceAccount:${var.project}.svc.id.goog[${helm_release.hashicorp_vault.namespace}/hashicorp-vault]"
}

resource "google_project_iam_custom_role" "hashicorp_vault_role" {
  project = var.project
  role_id = "hashicorp_vault"
  title   = "Hashicorp Vault"
  permissions = [
    "cloudkms.cryptoKeyVersions.useToEncrypt",
    "cloudkms.cryptoKeyVersions.useToDecrypt",
    "cloudkms.cryptoKeys.get",
  ]
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "cicd_bot_role_member" {
  project = var.project
  role    = google_project_iam_custom_role.hashicorp_vault_role.name
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.hashicorp_vault.email}"
}

resource "google_kms_key_ring" "hashicorp_vault" {
  project  = var.project
  location = var.region
  name     = "hashicorp-vault"
}

resource "google_kms_crypto_key" "hashicorp_vault_recovery_key" {
  name     = "hashicorp-vault-recovery-key"
  key_ring = google_kms_key_ring.hashicorp_vault.id
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "hashicorp_vault" {
  name             = "hashicorp-vault"
  repository       = "https://helm.releases.hashicorp.com"
  chart            = "vault"
  version          = var.hashicorp_vault_version
  namespace        = "hashicorp-vault"
  create_namespace = true
  set {
    name = "server.extraEnvironmentVars.VAULT_SEAL_TYPE"
    value = "gcpckms"
  }
  set {
    name = "server.extraEnvironmentVars.GOOGLE_PROJECT"
    value = var.project
  }
  set {
    name = "server.extraEnvironmentVars.GOOGLE_REGION"
    value = var.region
  }
  set {
    name = "server.extraEnvironmentVars.VAULT_GCPCKMS_SEAL_KEY_RING"
    value = google_kms_key_ring.hashicorp_vault.name
  }
  set {
    name = "server.extraEnvironmentVars.VAULT_GCPCKMS_SEAL_CRYPTO_KEY"
    value = google_kms_crypto_key.hashicorp_vault_recovery_key.name
  }
  set {
    name = "server.serviceaccount.annotations.iam\\.gke\\.io/gcp-service-account"
    value = google_service_account.hashicorp_vault.email
  }
}
```

After doing this, I noticed that my Hashicorp Vault pod was in error state, so I deleted it so it could pick up the new environment variables. Then, it came online with a message indicating that it was ready for "migration" to the new unsealing strategy.

Then, use the operator to migrate to the new sealing strategy:

```
vault operator unseal -migrate
```